# C# how to load friends email address and avatar?

Tags: c#, image, listview, datagridview, listbox

I'm struggling to find a way to load friends email and avatar from a database and put it into a DataGridView or ListView.

Current method: Using DataGridView:

```
        private void loadData()
    {
        var query = from o in Globals.DB.Friends
                    where o.UserEmail == Properties.Settings.Default.Email
                    select new
                    {
                        Avatar = o.Avatar,
                        FirstName = o.FirstName,
                        LastName = o.LastName,
                        Email = o.Email,
                        Display = o.Avatar + string.Format("{0} {1} - ({2})", o.FirstName, o.LastName, o.Email)
                    };
        FriendsDGV.DataSource = query.ToList();
    }
```

DataGridView doesn't provide value members or display members but a list box does:

```
        FriendsLb.DisplayMember = "Display";
        FriendsLb.ValueMember = "Avatar";
        FriendsLb.ValueMember = "Email";
        FriendsLb.ValueMember = "FirstName";
        FriendsLb.ValueMember = "LastName";
```

I'll need the value and display members in order for it to work but DataGridView doesn't provide it. I'm running out of ideas on how to load friends information and avatar into a data form such as: List box, DataGridView or List View. List view doesn't provide a data source so I don't even know what to do anymore Help! :(

Comment: you want to fetch the record from database and want to show in view??am i right?

Comment: Yes but I need to be able to display a image and a string

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc?